# Is Shaving allowed in honor of Shabbat this Tisha B'Av

Tags: shabbat, tisha-bav

This year Tisha B'Av falls on Shabbat.  Is shaving allowed in honor of Shabbat?

Comment: Why is this Shabbos different than any other Shabbos during the Nine Days?

Comment: A "psak halacha" VTC??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this site](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0itlLdAHlgoJ:https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp%3Fid%3D8354%20&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us):

> Many Ashkanazi Jews refrain from haircutting and shaving during the
>   Three Weeks, and even those who are lenient in this regard on Fridays,
>   in honor of the Sabbath, do not cut their hair or shave for Shabbat
>   Chazon. For Sephardi Jews it is permissible to shave and cut hair for
>   Shabbat Chazon. Even if Shabbat Chazon immediately precedes Tisha
>   B’Av, it is permissible, strictly speaking, according to Sephardic
>   custom, to shave or have one’s hair cut for the Sabbath. One who
>   chooses to behave stringently in this regard merits a divine blessing.

My own addition - Regarding Sephardim, their custom of mourning applies only to the week that Tish'a B'av occurs. When Tisha B'av occurs on Sunday or is postponed to Sunday, as it is this year and next (5778 and 5779), there is no such "week".

Comment: "One who chooses to behave stringently in this regard merits a divine blessing" - why?  There are two competing values, Shabbos and the 9 days.  There are different opinions on which one wins out.  How do you even define one as more stringent than the other?

Comment: @Heshy I don't see an ambiguity. The stringency refers to Sephardim. I.e., one may shave, but if you want to be stringent by not shaving b/c it's the Nine Days, he gets a divine blessing. The site does not provide a source for this explanation, and I'm not Sephardi, myself, to know what actually occurs. B"H, I'm thrilled with the blessings I already receive!

Comment: Yes, but if they're stringent on the 9 days they're lenient on kavod Shabbos at the same time.  If they're allowed to shave, they should be required to.

Comment: @Heshy You may be addressing a different opinion. Feel free to include that above or in your own answer. I don't claim that this is the only possible answer. It's just the one that I found from yeshiva. co.